# regular expression to search in xml file

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext3

i have a xml file a lot of links and some other information 
i want to extract these links from that xml to put them in another text file. 
i am using sublime 3 so i want a regular expression to search for links inside the xml file
here is some of the file

```
<Row ss:Height="13.8"><Cell ss:Formula="of:=HYPERLINK(&quot;http://csr.bu.edu/ftp/asl/asllvd/demos/verify_start_end_handshape_annotations//test_auto_move//signs_mov_separ_signers/Liz_10.mov&quot;; &quot;MOV&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String">MOV</Data></Cell></Row>
<Row ss:Height="13.8"><Cell ss:Formula="of:=HYPERLINK(&quot;http://csr.bu.edu/ftp/asl/asllvd/demos/verify_start_end_handshape_annotations//test_auto_move//signs_mov_separ_signers/Tyler_10.mov&quot;; &quot;MOV&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String">MOV</Data></Cell></Row>
<Row ss:Height="13.8"><Cell ss:Formula="of:=HYPERLINK(&quot;http://csr.bu.edu/ftp/asl/asllvd/demos/verify_start_end_handshape_annotations//test_auto_move//signs_mov_separ_signers/Naomi_10.mov&quot;; &quot;MOV&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String">MOV</Data></Cell></Row>
<Row ss:Index="7" ss:Height="13.8"><Cell ss:Formula="of:=HYPERLINK(&quot;http://csr.bu.edu/ftp/asl/asllvd/demos/verify_start_end_handshape_annotations//test_auto_move//signs_mov_separ_signers/Brady_10.mov&quot;; &quot;MOV&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String">MOV</Data></Cell></Row>
```

i want to exctract these links to be like this

```
http://csr.bu.edu/ftp/asl/asllvd/demos/verify_start_end_handshape_annotations//test_auto_move//signs_mov_separ_signers/Liz_10.mov
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Where's the `regex` you've attempted? That would be a start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not the best solution but it works

```
(http(s)??).+?(?=&quot)
```

Comment: just another question what if i want to get the word WEAVE from that xml line how to do this ? 
`<Row ss:Height="12.81"><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">WEAVE</Data></Cell></Row>`

Comment: @MustafaMancy `(?<=[>])[A-Z]+?(?=[<])`